# Cannot resolve symbol 'button' -Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a music player app but when I try to link two activities via a button I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'button'. I've tried importing button widget but still 'button' is highlighted in red. Alt+Enter doesn't solve. Any help??

Comment: Have you tried adding xml for the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things you might have forgotten to do:

- Name your button (give it an id), I think they're named button1, button2, ... by default
- Use a capital B when declaring the button object:

`Button myButton = new Button("play music");`

You should make sure you have Button imported in the activity where you want a button (I think you do)

You can add a button with xml, like so:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button_id"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/play_music_button" />
```

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this as well after updating my android studio. For some reason when you declare a button, the AS doesnt automatically add it to your imports as it does for EditText, TextView ect.

SO just scroll up and import it as such and you problem will be solved.

```
import android.widget.Button;
```